# How to link get method of java servlet to bootstrap dropdown menu

Tags: java, twitter-bootstrap, servlets

I'm new at front end programming.
I wrote a java servlet and I would like to call its get method by clicking on a voice of a dropdown menu that I built with twitter bootstrap. This one is included in a navbar.
Can someone explain how to do it?

Comment: Learn how HTTP works. Learn how `Servlet` containers work. Learn what `ajax` is. Use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linking front-end without refreshing the page is done with AJAX.

First, I suggest you look into javascript AJAx tutorial

```
http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_intro.asp
```

Next, after you've gained some insight on how AJAX works, use jquery to

use AJAX and communicate with your backend servlets.

Comment: `w3schools` is generally regarded as a poor resource.

Comment: I think it's good enough to get an insight on what AJAX is and how it's done. If you're just going to copy someone else's code, then there're a lot of other resources on the web.